# Merging issues in Redmine

Tags: merge, redmine, issue-tracking, redmine-plugins

An interesting feature in Redmine was the possibility to merge two or more issues into one new issue.
This feature was asked to development team but still isn't available.
Someone can help me with a workaround to implement this functionality?

Comment: There aren't any plugins I know of that do this. I was hoping it would be included early on in the [ChiliProject](https://www.chiliproject.org/) fork but I don't think it's gone anywhere yet. For now it's got to be "mark related as 'duplactes' and close" - not an ideal solution

Answer (score 8):

up until now my workaround is:

For example you have yyy and zzz issue, yyy is the one that will be merged with zzz.

1. Changes the yyy status to "rejected".
2. Put "merge issue with #zzz" in yyy comment field (redmine will automatically convert #zzz into link).
3. set the parent task for yyy as zzz, now when you open zzz you will see yyy as its subtask.

It serves my needs just fine as the two issue would still be linked (albeit manually).